# How to "bond" sshd to only a given interface?

Tags: ssh, openbsd

How can I limit sshd to only listen on given interface when using OpenBSD 5.3?

Comment: @slm I wouldn't consider that a duplicate. It just happens to use sshd for the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `sshd_config` man page:

> `ListenAddress`
>
> Specifies the local addresses sshd(8) should listen on. The following forms may be used:
>
> - `ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr|IPv6_addr`
> - `ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr:port`
> - `ListenAddress [host|IPv6_addr]:port`
>
> If *port* is not specified, `sshd` will listen on the address and all prior `Port` options specified. The default is to listen on all local addresses. Multiple `ListenAddress`
>   options are permitted. Additionally, any `Port` options must precede this option for non-port qualified addresses.

More generally, for `ssh` and `sshd`, note that the documentation is split between `sshd(8)`, `ssh(1)`, `sshd_config(5)` and `ssh_config(5)`,

Comment: so I have to use pf to only allow sshd to listen on given interfaces?